# Calculate average gray value of a sub-image specifed by row and column indexing in MATLAb

Tags: image, matlab, indexing

I have an image and I want to calculate the average gray value of different patches of the image.
I started with defining a patch using a row and column index. This is how I specify my where my subimage is located.

```
for x = 10 : 1 : 74
    for y = 30 : 1 : 94            
    .........
    end
end`
```

Now how do I calculate the average gray value of this subimage? I know that all this means is finding the mean(mean(image)). But since I have only the row and column positions, how can I apply this same concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
mean(mean(im(10:74,30:94)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is some MxN matrix why don't you create a submatrix and calculate the mean over that?

eg:

```
subimage = image(10:74, 30:94);
mean_grey = mean(mean(subimage))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt really know it is so easy to specify a sum-image.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution: convolve the image (`I`) with a flat kernel (`h`) (size of your 'sub-image') and take the value of the result at any index.

```
h = ones(a,b); % sub-image is size a x b
h = h / sum(h(:));
J = imfilter(I, h);
% J(x,y) will give you the average of a sub-image centered on (x,y)
```

Edge cases may cause strange behavior (sub-image out of image range), but you can supply a third argument to `imfilter` to address this.